# Habilitar botão quando a última requisição for executada com sucesso

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, get, callback

Pessoal estou querendo habilitar um botão somente quando a última requisição post via Ajax for executada com sucesso.

Tenho uma tabela com vários registros com suas respectivas informações e `ids`.
Ao clicar num botão faço uma requisição via post e Ajax individual dessa linha da tabela.

Mas tenho um outro botão que percorre toda a tabela pegando seus respectivos `ids` e fazendo as requisições individualmente.

Ao terminar todas as requisições é que habilito ou não um botão para continuar.

O problema é quando capturar a última requisição desses registros. Não estou conseguindo.

Meu código:

```
function calculaMedia(aluno) {
   $.when( calculaMediaFuncao(aluno, function(){}) ).then(function(ret){       
      console.log(ret);
      console.log( "Disparei assim que as requisições se completaram" );
      return true;
   }).fail(function(){
      console.log( "Disparei se uma ou mais requisições falharam" );
      return false;
   });
}

function calculaMediaFuncao(aluno, callback) {
   $.post( "/index.php?r=aluno%2Fnota-aluno&aluno="+aluno+"&disc="+disc+"&tipo="+tipo+"&ap="+notaAP, function( data ) {
      $( "#situacaoFinal_"+aluno ).html( data );
      callback( true );
   }).fail(function() {
   callback( false );
   })
}

function calcularNotas() {
   $("#btnGravarNotas").removeAttr("disabled");
   $('#tabelaAlunos > tbody  > tr').each(function(key, data) {
      var aluno = $(data).attr('data-aluno-id');
      console.log(aluno);
      calculaMediaFuncao(aluno, function (res) {
         if (!res) {
            $("#btnGravarNotas").attr("disabled", "disabled");                                  
         }
      });
   });
}
```

Individualmente eu chamo por `calculaMedia(aluno)`.

Mas quando clicar num botão tem que chamar todos os registros e só habilitar o botão quando a última requisição for completada e for `true`.

Alguém me ajuda...

Comment: Você conseguirá melhores respostas se der às pessoas código que elas possam usar para reproduzir o problema.

Answer (score 1):

em sua função você pode passar mais um valor

```
function calcularNotas(aluno, numero) {
```

e fazer uma consulta se esse numero é igual ao ultimo numero

```
if(numero == ultimo_numero){
   $('#botao_que_eu_quero_habilitar').prop('disabled', false);
}
```

mas como saber qual o ultimo numero?
vai depender de como está sendo montada sua tabela, estática ou dinâmica. se for estática é fácil por exemplo:

a tabela contem fixo 10 alunos e isso não muda, então é só atribuir:

```
ultimo_numero = 10;
```

se a tabela for montada dinamicamente e você não tem controle de quantos alunos podem vir, então na hora da montagem você define o valor dessa variável no ultimo item da tabela, por exemplo:

```
//possivelmente um for que é usado pra montar dinamicamente sua tabela
for(i = 0; i < lista.lenght(); i++){

   //aqui a verificação se é o ultimo item
   if(i+1==lista.lenght()){
     numero = i;
   }

}
```

e ai você passa esse numero na função, assim como você passa o aluno:

```
calcularNotas(aluno, numero);
```

Comment: Eu pensei isso também. A tabela é dinâmica mas tem sim como pegar o último numero. O "problema" é que só deve ser habilitada se não houve nenhum erro na inserção dos dados. Como falei, a função percorre todas as linhas da tabela fazendo algumas verificações, pois são inseridos valores para cada registro da tabela. No callback da função calculaMediaFuncao() se não nenhum erro retorna true, caso contrario vai retornar false. Então se em algum momento, quando estiver percorrendo os registros da tabela, essa verificação falhar, não deve ser habilitado o botão de continuar.

Comment: Poxa @JoséAriJunior entao voce fez a pergunta errada 'última requisição for completada e for true.' Mas nesse caso tambem é possivel, usa uma variavel global como esse retorno e deixa um if pra nao alterar ela se ela for preenchida como false, se ela tiver false vc nao habilita, se tiver true vc habilita

Comment: Verdade!! Da proxima vez vou formular diretinho a pergunta! ;-D

Answer (score 1):

Consegui utilizando a dica do JulioHenrique97 com uma adaptação.

Na hora a gente nao lembra mas depois a luzinha acende.. rsrsrs

```
function calcularNotas() {
    var ultAluno = "";
    var habilita = true;
    $(\'#tabelaAlunos > tbody  > tr\').each(function(key, data) {
        ultAluno = $(data).attr(\'data-aluno-id\');
    });
    $(\'#tabelaAlunos > tbody  > tr\').each(function(key, data) {
        var aluno = $(data).attr(\'data-aluno-id\');
        calculaMediaFuncao(aluno, function (res) {
            if (!res) {
                habilita = false;
            }
            if (aluno === ultAluno && habilita) { 
                $("#btnGravarNotas").prop("disabled", false);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Como eu sempre digo: só não tem jeito pra morte! huashuahsuhasu
Valew JulioHenrique97!!

Comment: hahaha nada, ja foram luzinhas pra min muitas vezes tb